# Prove that propositional Aczel slash is closed under deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, intuitionistic-logic

I have already proved that
$ \Gamma |\phi \Rightarrow \Gamma \vdash_{IPC} \phi $.

On the other hand, I have tried to prove the other side. I used induction on the length of the proof.(I used natural deduction without RAA rule). But I could not prove it for the or-elimination rule.

Propositional Aczel slash:

$ \Gamma | P \equiv \Gamma \vdash_{IPC} P \text{ for prime sentences P}  $

$ \Gamma | \phi_{1} \land \phi_{2} \equiv \Gamma | \phi_{1} \text{ and } \Gamma |\phi_{2}  $

$ \Gamma | \phi_{1} \lor \phi_{2} \equiv \Gamma | \phi_{1} \text{ or } \Gamma |\phi_{2}  $

$ \Gamma | \phi_{1} \rightarrow \phi_{2} \equiv \Gamma \vdash_{IP} \phi_{1} \rightarrow \phi_{2} \text{ and,  if }\Gamma | \phi_{1} \text{ then } \Gamma |\phi_{2}  $

or-elimination:
[or-elimination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEh2z.png)

Please help me for the case of or-elimination.

Comment: I must be missing something here: according to the rules you gave, I would think that $P \lor Q \vdash_{IPC} P \lor Q$ but $P \lor Q \nmid P \lor Q$ for atomic proposition variables $P, Q$.